# CMD not working outside "legacy mode"

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I tried disabling "legacy mode" in CMD, to access some customization features. I did this by Right clicking the upper bar --> Defaults and then unchecking "legacy mode"

Problem is that when I start cmd now, nothing happens inside the window and I can't write anything. It looks like this when started:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer from ALEXANDERKRIŠŠ over [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/command-prompt-only-works-in-legacy-console-mode/14de7bef-2823-4fc2-b6cf-9651c681caf2) did it for me:

> in properties of terminal, tab Terminal uncheck Terminal color for foreground and background

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried renaming or deleting Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console in  the registry and rebooting? This will reset all layout settings for CMD and Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run the cmd form start menu. Run it by pressing Windows+Run, type cmd and press Enter. Also, delete the cmd shortcut in start menu.

Comment: Why, what does that do?